# Hit and run MCMC

Tags: r, bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo

I'm trying to implement the hit and run MCMC algorithm, but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to go about it. The general idea, is as follows:

> To generate a proposal jump in MH, we:
>
> - Generate a direction $d$ from a
>     distribution on the surface of the
>     unit sphere $\mathcal{O}$
> - Generate
>     a signed distance $\lambda$ along the
>     constrained space.

However, I have no idea of how I should go about implementing this in R (or any other language).

Does anyone have a snippet of code that would point me in the right direction?

BTW, I not that interested in a library that does this method, I want to try and code it up myself.

Many thanks.

Comment: Never heard of this algorithm before, but it sounds pretty interesting. Could you provide a link to a explanatory source ? Thank you !

Comment: @steffen Here's a link to the [original paper](http://ioe.engin.umich.edu/techrprt/pdf/TR81-01.pdf) - well actually the technical report. I've never used this procedure either.

Comment: What is the advantage of the hit and run MCMC over other methods? Speed of convergence?

Comment: @fRed: That's why I offered the bounty. I've read about Hit and run, but don't know under what circumstances it would be useful.

Comment: Would you tell us why you want to use this instead of one of the more established MCMC-algorithms?

Comment: I think the hit-and-run algorithm did not do well in the long run simply because it is mostly a "shot in the dark", i.e. the unbounded space equivalent of a uniform proposal. If the dimension is large and the distribution of the radius $\lambda$ unrelated to the problem, there is no chance one proposal hits a region of interest!

Comment: Link is now broken.

Comment: Is this the paper? https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/3513/bal7884.0001.001.pdf?sequence=5 @daknowles

Answer (score 10):

I didn't look at the paper you supplied, but let me have a go anyway:

If you have a $p$-dimensional parameter space you can generate a random direction $d$ uniformly distributed on the surface of the unit sphere with

```
x <- rnorm(p)
d <- x/sqrt(sum(x^2))
```

(c.f. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersphere#Generating_random_points)).

Then, use this to generate proposals for $d$ for rejection sampling (assuming you can actually evaluate the distribution for $d$).

Assuming you start in position $x$ and have accepted a $d$, generate a proposal $y$ with

```
 lambda <- r<SOMEDISTRIBUTION>(foo, bar)
 y <- x + lambda * d
```

and do a Metropolis-Hastings-Step to decide whether to move to $y$ or not.

Of course, how well this can work will depend on the distribution of $d$ and how expensive it is to (repeatedly) evaluate its density in the rejection sampling step, but since generating proposals for $d$ is cheap you may get away with it.

---

Added for @csgillespie's benefit:

From what I was able to gather by some googling, hit-and-run MCMC is useful primarily for fast mixing if you have a (multivariate) target that has arbitrary bounded but not necessarily connected support, because it enables you to move from any point in the support to any other in one step. More [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=1-ffZVmazvwC&pg=PA173&dq=hit-and-run++MCMC&hl=de&ei=jL0ATdG3JozLswbOwfzyDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=hit-and-run%20%20MCMC&f=false) and [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/harin/L1.pdf).

Comment: If this answer is not satisfactory, could you explain why?

Comment: I'm not sure about @fred, but when I offered the bounty I suppose I was wanting a bit more insight into hit-and-run MCMC. For example, what types of problems would it be best suited for. Of course, if there are no other answers, then this question would win the bounty.

Comment: @csgillespie: I edited my answer to better accomodate your interest. Let it not be said that I was undeserving of the bounty. ;)

Comment: Many thanks for the link. One of the reasons I placed the bounty was that my google searches turned up a few mathematical discussions of the method, but little in the way of practical applications. Please don't take it as a slight if I wait another 48 hours before awarding the bounty (it is a particularly generous bounty!)

Answer (score 4):

I came across your question when I was looking for the original reference for Hit-and-Run.  Thanks for that!  I just put together a proof-of-concept implementation of hit-and-run for PyMC at the end of [this recent blog](http://healthyalgorithms.wordpress.com/2011/01/28/mcmc-in-python-pymc-step-methods-and-their-pitfalls).